# Should I be using a three-level or two-level MLM?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, nested-data

I am running the following study, and I am unsure about the best analytical approach. I have two ideas, but I'm not sure either one is correct. I am grateful for any feedback.

I am conducting a study to understand better how people use different environmental features to learn specific paths. I plan to have participants navigate a novel environment ten times. The environment contains three types of features that are next to decision points (i.e., junctions where they must choose a direction to travel). No choice point will have more than one feature. There will be five choice points for each type of feature. We will measure errors at decision points.

My main research question is: does the type of feature affect learning over repeated trials? In particular, I hypothesize that one type of feature better facilitates learning. Thus, I anticipate fewer errors at those choice points, either from the very beginning or a larger (negative) slope.

My plan was to use a multilevel model. I had two possible models I was thinking about using. I plan to use `lmer()` in R.

In the two-level model, trial would be at level one and participant at level two. Each trial would consist of three observations (i.e., number of errors at the choice points containing one of the three features). The model would like this:

`two.level.model <- lmer(errors ~ trial * feature + (trial | participant)`

The second option I was thinking about stems from reading about item response theory. I was wondering if I should treat it as a three-level model with individual choice points at level one, trials at level two, and participants at level three. In this case, I would have one observation at each choice point (i.e., correct or incorrect). I’m not entirely sure what the model would look like, but I think something like this:

`three.level.model <- glmer(error ~ feature + (1 | feature) + (1 | trial) + (1 | participant), data = df, family = binomial())`

My main question is, Does one model better answer my research question than another model? (Maybe I should be asking, Does either model answer my research questions?)

If I understand it correctly, the two-level model treats all choice points with a given type of feature as being equivalent. The three-level model would allow me to ask additional questions (e.g., do participants make fewer errors earlier or later in the environment). Can I still reasonably answer my main question using this three-level model, though?

I appreciate any feedback or help you can provide. Thanks to so many different message boards I feel like I am gaining a better grasp of multilevel modeling, though I still have a LONG way to go!

Edit to answer some clarifying questions:

The environment is the same for all trials and all participants. Nothing changes across the trials. The environment is relatively complex (think large outdoor maze). In total, there are 15 choice points (each containing 5 of the same kind of feature). I apologize for not better explaining the errors. In the two-level model I was anticipating using the total number of errors made for the 5 choice points with a given feature. If I do the three-level model, it would be a dichotomous correct/incorrect.

Comment: Is the novel environment the same for a participant across all ten trials? If yes, is the novel environment the same across all participants? (I am thinking that the environment would be something like a room, say.)

Comment: Assuming the environment stays the same within and across participants, can you clarify what changes across the ten trials for a participant - if anything? For example, do the features change at all across trials for that participants or do they stay the same?

Comment: How many choice points are there in total for your environment and how do you decide what choice point gets what feature associated with it?  Also, how do you measure and express the errors associated with a choice point?

Comment: It seems that you have measurements (i.e., errors) associated with each participant by choice point combination? Not clear whether those measurements are expressed as binary (error vs. no error) or as a number of errors. It seems to me that you might (?) have participant and choice point as crossed random effects and for each combination of participant and choice point, you have repeated trials where you measure "errors" incurred at that choice point. But I am not sure, since some details of your model design are not clear to me.

Comment: The environment is the same for all trials and all participants. Nothing changes across the trials. The environment is relatively complex (think large outdoor maze). In total, there are 15 choice points (each containing 5 of the same kind of feature). I apologize for not better explaining the errors. In the two-level model I was anticipating using the total number of errors made for the 5 choice points with a given feature. If I do the three-level model, it would be a dichotomous correct/incorrect. Thank you for your clarifying questions!

Comment: So all subjects see the same environment.  For each subject, the 15 choice points are the same across the 10 trials.  Each choice point is associated with a particular feature, such that 5 choice points are associated with feature #1, 5 choice points are associated with feature #2 and 5 choice points are associated with feature #3.  Is this association exactly the same for all participants? (In other words, if choice point #1 is associated with feature #2 for the first participant, this association will be the same for all other participants, etc.)

Comment: Yes, everything you said is correct. Yes, our plan was to make the association consistent for all participants.